# What is the double exclamation mark mean beside clip in mail.app

Tags: macos, mail.app

[image: mail with double exclamation]

I have received a mail, which has a double exclamation mark beside the attachment file clip, what did it mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means the email was marked as very important or urgent by the original sender.

Comment: Just looked up how this works, and [RFC2156](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2156#section-2.2.2) allows an `Importance` header, and some senders also send `X-Priority` header too. I'm not sure which one macOS Mail is picking up on, but likely one of those two. I just saw this on a recruitment email, and got concerned, because I was like "where are those !! coming from? is this spam?? am I vulnerable now that I've opened the email???" so, thanks RFC2156, I guess